# Numpy broadcast using dictionary of index conversion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dictionary of index conversions:

`d = {0:[0,1,3], 1:[4,5,6], 2:[2,7,8], 3:[9]...}`

where keys (0,1,2,3...) represent the indices in array 1 and values represent the list of equivalent indices in array 2.

Given array 1 of shape `(len(d.keys()), n)` where `n` is a constant. Is it possible to broadcast array 1 to create array 2 of shape `(sum([len(value) for value in d.values()]), n)`.

Here is what I have done so far using a `for` loop:

```py
d = {0:[0,1,3], 1:[4,5,6], 2:[2,7,8], 3:[9]}

arr1 = np.array([[0,1],
                 [np.NaN,np.NaN],
                 [np.NaN,6.5],
                 [16,0.2]])

arr2 = np.full((10,2),np.NaN)

for idx in np.unique(np.where(~np.isnan(arr1))[0]):

    new_idx = d[idx]
    arr2[new_idx,:] = arr1[idx,:]
```

The actual arr1 I am working with has shape `(600,n)` and it is sparse (lots of np.NaN values) which is why I set the default values of arr2 to np.NaN and iterate through non NaN rows. The actual arr2 has shape `(198812,n)`. Any suggestions for how to speed up this conversion with a vectorized operation that doesn't involve a `for` loop?

Comment: please provide the expected output, your code is not running

Comment: sorry there was a typo, it should have said arr2 = np.full((10,2),np.NaN). I have fixed this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach, but you'll necessarily have to loop at some point (here to reconstruct the dictionary):

```
d2 = {v: k for k,l in d.items() for v in l}
# {0: 0, 1: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 2: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 3}

arr2 = np.full((10,2), np.NaN)

arr2[list(d2)] = arr1[list(d2.values())]
```

output:

```
array([[ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ nan,  6.5],
       [ 0. ,  1. ],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  6.5],
       [ nan,  6.5],
       [16. ,  0.2]])
```

Comment: FYI, I tested this out with %%timeit. In this example, your answer is 4x faster than using the ``for`` loop. However, when I use the actual arrays that are much larger, the ``for`` loop is faster -- even if I iterate through every row of the small array using ``for idx in range(arr1.shape[0]):``. I tried converting the dictionary keys and values to lists ahead of time but this doesn't speed anything up. Any idea why this method is slower?

Comment: How much slower? No, I don't have an idea.

Comment: 16.2 ms ± 290 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each) using the ``for`` loop. 64.5 ms ± 909 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) using this method. The only technical difference is that I'm indexing smaller portions of the array at a time, whereas this indexes the entire array at once. I can't imagine why the loop would be faster.